# Igualar dados de tabelas em servidores LinkedServer

Tags: sql, sql-server

tenho 3 servidores LinkedServer (os 3 possuindo as mesmas tabelas com os mesmos campos).

Servidor 1: Primeiro_Servidor

Tabela: Teste

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Servidor 2: Segundo_Servidor

Tabela: Teste

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Servidor 3: Terceiro_Servidor

Tabela: Teste

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Select para retornar os campos da tabela "Teste" no "Primeiro_Servidor":

```
SELECT id, username, password FROM OPENQUERY(Primeiro_Servidor, 'SELECT id, username, password FROM Teste')
```

Eu gostaria de pegar a tabela "Teste" do servidor 1 por exemplo, e replicar todos os dados dela na tabela "Teste" dos servidores 2 e 3 (verificando se o id existe. se existir, fazer um update, se não existir, inserir). Alguém poderia me indicar como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: Essas tabelas têm relacionamentos

Comment: Não possuem relacionamentos.

Comment: SQL server ou MySQL

Comment: Muito importante que tipo de replicação automática, por execução de tarefas

Comment: Elas podem não ter relacionamento, mas provavelmente o campo Id é identity com auto-incremento... se você já fez algum insert antes nessas outras bases, vai precisar desligar ele reiniciar o índice.

Comment: Você pode executar a query usando um `select` normal prefixiando com o nome no link:  `select * from nome_link_server1.nome_banco.dbo.teste` e dai é fácil fazer um join e um update

Comment: Se quiser igualar todas as tabelas, para evitar validação do tipo `exists`, use o comando `merge`, que funciona com *linked servers*

Comment: SQLServer... Coloquei esses 3 servidores como exemplo, mas pode ocorrer de entrarem mais servidores. Pra isso, tenho uma tabela que guarda o nome de todos os servidores linked servers

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução típica de replicação envolve o uso de dois comandos em uma mesma transação, um para atualizar as linhas existentes na tabela remota e outro para acrescentar as linhas inexistentes na tabela remota:

```
-- código #1
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- atualiza informações existentes no servidor remoto (R)
UPDATE R
  set username= L.username,
      password= L.password 
  from Segundo_Servidor.banco.esquema.Teste as R
       inner join Teste as L on R.id = L.id
  where L.username <> R.username
        or L.password <> R.password;

-- acrescenta informações inexistentes no servidor remoto (R)
INSERT into Segundo_Servidor.banco.esquema.Teste (id, username, password)
  SELECT L.id, L.username, L.password
    from Teste as L
    where not exists (SELECT * 
                        from Segundo_Servidor.banco.esquema.Teste as R
                        where R.id = L.id);

COMMIT;
```

O código acima é executado no servidor local (L), isto é, o primeiro servidor. Ou seja, ele *empurra* os dados para o servidor remoto (R).

Também é possível outra solução, com código de replicação sendo executado em cada servidor remoto, *puxando* os dados:

```
-- código #2
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- atualiza informações existentes no servidor local
UPDATE L
  set username= PS.username,
      password= PS.password 
  from Primeiro_Servidor.banco.esquema.Teste as PS
       inner join Teste as L on PS.id = L.id
  where L.username <> PS.username
        or L.password <> PS.password;

-- acrescenta informações inexistentes no servidor local
INSERT into Teste (id, username, password)
  SELECT PS.id, PS.username, PS.password
    from Primeiro_Servidor.banco.esquema.Teste as PS
    where not exists (SELECT * 
                        from Teste s L
                        where PS.id = L.id);

COMMIT;
```

A vantagem do código #2 é que ele pode ser transformado em procedimento armazenado no servidor principal e executado remotamente com EXECUTE AT a partir do servidor principal. Ou seja, uma única versão do código, mantida no servidor principal, mas executada em cada servidor remoto a partir do servidor principal:

```
-- código #3
EXECUTE (...) AT Segundo_Servidor;
EXECUTE (...) AT Terceiro_Servidor;
```

---

Entretanto, seja *empurrando* ou *puxando* os dados, esse tipo de replicação gera tráfego excessivo na rede, pois para saber se a linha existe ou não no outro servidor, na prática o conteúdo da tabela (remota ou local, dependendo se *empurrando* ou *puxando*) trafega pela rede.

Há formas de otimizar os códigos acima. Mas a sugestão é que avalie a implementação de algum tipo de replicação automática fornecida pelo SQL Server.

PS: não testei as soluções propostas acima; espero que não contenham erro.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer um insert direto de um select é claro mas pq fazer isso se vc tem uma ferramenta grátis para fazer comparação de dados do MS SQL Server?

Qualquer versão do **Visual Studio** tem uma ferramenta para [**comparação de dados**](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/pt-br/vs/features/ssdt/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F) e schema que pode conectar a duas bases e comparar as diferenças.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Selecione duas bases que podem estar em dois servidores diferentes...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você escolhe as tabelas que serão comparadas, note que para poder comparar registro-a-registro a tabela precisa ter uma PK ou pelo menos uma chave única (bem precisa de qualquer maneira saber qual registro comparar com qual).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Você pode inclusive aplicar as diferenças igualando os dados ou gerar um script que fará isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Além do mais há muita [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn266028(v=vs.103).aspx) na web de como usar esse recurso. Mesmo que você não tenha o **Visual Studio** (que qualquer desenvolvedor que trabalhe com .Net vai ter) instalado, o download dessa versão que te mostrei é grátis.